# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

Tags: python, eclipse, matplotlib, anaconda

Llevo unos dias con el mismo problema y no logro encontrarle solucion, he probado a desinstalar el matplotlib y volver a instalarlo desde el anaconda pero tampoco me ha dado resultado. La cosa es que cuando escribo pip freeze, me sale que esta instalado el matplotlib, pero despues, a la hora de importarlo en el eclipse, me sale el error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib', si alguien pudiera ayudarme lo agradeceria mucho porque ya es que estoy desesperado

Comment: Comprueba el entorno virtual. En anaconda, al instalar un paquete, sea con `conda` o con `pip`, se instala sólo en el entorno virtual activo. Es posible que eclipse esté usando otro entorno virtual, o ninguno (tendrías que configurar eclipse para que use el entorno virtual correspondiente).

Comment: Como comprobaria el entorno, esque soy nuevo y no se muy bn como funciona eclipse

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [ModuleNotFoundError No puedo importar un módulo instalado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/404776/modulenotfounderror-no-puedo-importar-un-m%c3%b3dulo-instalado)

Answer (score 1):

Prueba ejecutando esto en python, a mi me funcionó cuando en jupyter no me lo detectaba aunque lo había instalado previamente.

```
import pip
pip.main(["install","matplotlib"])
```

El crédito de esta solución es para: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49187173/1827690

Answer (score -1):

Me paso lo mismo, así que fui al cmd y ejecuté el comando:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

[image: resumen de la ejecución del comando superio]

Luego ejecute en el Script de Python en RStudio:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```